# Spring Cloud Sleuth with MySQL

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am stucked to find any proper example which can demonstrate me to find out traces and store it in MySQL database locally.
I have used zipkin server to visualize my distrubuted tracing of microservices.
If any one worked with Spring Cloud Sleuth with gradle in latest version please handover the perfect Example which can help me.

Here' my code:

build.gradle

```java
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR4")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.16'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.zipkin.zipkin2/zipkin-storage-mysql-v1
    implementation group: 'io.zipkin.zipkin2', name: 'zipkin-storage-mysql-v1', version: '2.23.2'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.5.0'

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

application.properties

```java
server.port=8083
spring.application.name=service1
#logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=DEBUG
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=1.0
spring.zipkin.enabled=true
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://localhost:9411/
spring.sleuth.enabled=true

spring.zipkin.storage.type=mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zipkin
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:mysql.sql
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.sleuth.web.enabled=true

spring.zipkin.sender.type=web
```

Controller.class

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpaceShipRestController {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/service1")
    public String service1() {
        log.info("service1 start");
        String service2 = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8090/service2", String.class);
        String service3 = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9090/service3", String.class);
        log.info("call" + service2 + "and" + service3);
        return "calling service2";
    }
}
```

Apllication.class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MySQLStorage mySQLStorage(DataSource datasource) {
        return MySQLStorage.newBuilder().datasource(datasource).executor(Runnable::run).build();
    }
}
```

**I have Used *zipkin-server-2.23.2-exec* jar to lauch server on port localhost:9411 as default port**
using this command on cmd.  *java -jar zipkin-server-2.23.2-exec*

My zipkin is up and working fine i am just stucked to store the traces in my MySQL DB the tables are getting created properly. But the record are empty.
I don't no why i think i am missing any configuration.
I followed [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/51664085427/) article as they shown to store traces in DB.
Can anyone suggest me where i am missing to evalute.

[image: My zipkin UI looks like]

[image: My MySQL DB]

Answer (score 0):

Please use Spring Cloud Sleuth 3.1.0-SNAPSHOT (via the 2021.0.0-SNAPSHOT train, we should have M1 in June AFAIR). Here you can find a sample https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples/tree/3.1.x/data (remember about this part https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples/blob/3.1.x/data/pom.xml#L33-L38) and the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/integrations.html#sleuth-jdbc-integration . For your convenience I'm copying the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.sleuthsamples</groupId>
    <artifactId>data</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SLEUTH</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Either p6spy or datasource-proxy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
            <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Either p6spy or datasource-proxy -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ttddyy</groupId>
            <artifactId>datasource-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
                </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-plugin-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-plugin-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

If you don't want to use snapshots, you need to use Brave's p6spy support https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/instrumentation/p6spy . Please add `io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-p6spy` to the classpath and change the properties as presented in the project's readme

Comment: Thanks for answering @Marcin Grzejszczak

Comment: Actually I want to know the procedure for storing and creating table in MySQL  would you plz help me with that or just suggest any simple implementaion of example **application.properties** and **build.gradle** to create a connection with MySQl DB and create the table which will have column with traceId, sapnId, etc

Comment: So this is completely sth different. Why would you want to do that? Start a zipkin instance with mysql datastore and you have it already prepared.

Comment: Hey @Marcin Grzejszczak I have just edited my question with my code can you just review it as i need to store my traceIds and SpanIdsas in Db. Zipkin washout all the traces when server gets down so i just need to store it with MySql.